# EmberJS iterate over object in template

Tags: javascript, loops, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to iterate over an object in EmberJS but I get the error that `{{#each}}` must be used on an array.

So is there a method to iterate over an object?

I am getting data from the model and building an object in the controller for rendering purposes.

Controller:

```
listData: function () {
  // data = {foos: {foo: 'bar'}, bars: {bar: 'foo'}}

  return data; 
}
```

Template:

```
{{#each listData}}
  {{this.foo}} // Bar
  {{this.bar}} // Foo
```

I have had a look at the question this is marked a duplicate of but that question involves a models properties and an `Ember.Object()` and converting the result into an array. I need to keep it as an object (normal JS object). and iterate over this in handlebars template.

Comment: It isn't possible, hence the duplicate.  You can't iterate over an object in ember handlebars.

Answer (score 3):

In Ember **v2.0.0-beta.1** you can iterate over object properties using `{{each-in}}` helper. For example, following code:

```
{{#each-in listData as |key value|}}
  <li>Value.foo:`{{value.foo}}` Value.bar:`{{value.bar}}`</li>
{{/each-in}}
```

For `listData` you've supplied in question:

```
listData: Ember.computed(function () {
  return {foos: {foo: 'bar'}, bars: {bar: 'foo'}};
})
```

Produces following output:

```
Value.foo:`bar` Value.bar:``
Value.foo:`` Value.bar:`foo`
```

[Demo on JS Bin.](http://jsbin.com/pukunejuse/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: thanks! it will take some time before I can find things in their documentation. The search they have doesn't do a very good job in finding the keywords

Answer (score 0):

I would have to see more of your controller to see why you're getting the 'must be an Array' error, but my guess is it's directly related to how your data is set. Your data object is not an array.

One other item that may be causing an issue is if you're returning data from the controller to be rendered on the template, you need to specify it as a property in the controller.

```
listData: function(){
    //data = [{foos: {foo: 'bar'}, bars: {bar: 'foo'}}]
    return data;
}.property('listData'),
```

This will then be allow the template to iterate over the data object.

See this jsbin:

http://jsbin.com/ucanam/5065/